# Are multiple favicon sizes necessary?

Tags: html, favicon

I am working on a site redesign, which includes a new favicon. The current site specified all of the following sizes:

```
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/img/apple-icon-57x57.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/img/apple-icon-60x60.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/img/apple-icon-72x72.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/img/apple-icon-76x76.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/img/apple-icon-114x114.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/img/apple-icon-120x120.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/img/apple-icon-144x144.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/img/apple-icon-152x152.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/img/apple-icon-180x180.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="/img/android-icon-192x192.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/img/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/img/favicon-96x96.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/img/favicon-16x16.png">
```

Personally, I have never done this. I have always simply created a single, large (192x192) png and allowed the browser/device to resize it as it needs. Yes, technically this may lead to some artifacts if the relation between the source and destination sizes are not evenly divisible. But if the source material is sufficiently large (as 192x192 is, currently), this is a minor issue. Additionally, the single-PNG approach seems to be compatible with all major, modern browsers, and in my own tests seems to look good. Yes, the file size is marginally larger, but we are talking only a few kilobytes difference here.

Of course, if you wanted to customize the design of each size, then different files would be necessary. But assuming your 192x192 is the same graphic as your 16x16, in 2019, is there any reason to specify so many versions of a favicon?

Answer (score 9):

RealFaviconGenerator's author speaking.

Wherever you found this snippet, I probably wrote it in the first place. RealFaviconGenerator has been the first to generate so many icons. That was a feature. And several other services simply took this as a reference.

But you guess right: you only need the 180x180 Touch icon. iOS devices can scale it down. The only concrete case where you would like to declare them all is when the scaling algorithm of iOS (a variant of Cubic) is not optimal, for example with pixel art. See 
https://realfavicongenerator.net/blog/how-ios-scales-the-apple-touch-icon/ (I wrote this article). Now, by default, RealFaviconGenerator creates only the 180x180 icon.

For desktop icons (16x16, 32x32 and 96x96 in your example), this is, for me, work-in-progress. I need to test all these sizes, along with multiple-size `favicon.ico`, on latest and older browsers. So far I didn't take the time to go through all these experiments and RealFaviconGenerator might be too verbose in this regard.

Comment: Any update? I'm wondering *which* browsers are left over today when using a single, say 256x256, icon. A single icon does work fine in IE11, and latest Edge, Firefox and Chrome. So at least modern *desktop* browsers seem to be covered.